# Why spreading the next object is emptying the array property field that only exists in the first object?

Tags: reactjs, api, slug

```
const initialState = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  price: '',
  categories: [],
  category: '',
  subCategoriesList: [],
  subs: [],
  shipping: '',
  quantity: '',
  images: [],
  colors: ['Black', 'Brown', 'Silver', 'White', 'Blue'],
  brands: ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Microsoft', 'Lenovo', 'ASUS', 'Dell'],
  color: '',
  brand: '',
}

const ProductUpdate = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)
  const authToken = user?.token

  const router = useRouter()

  const {
    query: { slug },
  } = router

  useEffect(() => {
  // with this loadCategories function, values.categories array get filled
    loadCategories()
    if (!slug && !values.categories) {
      return
    }
  //as soon as loadProductInfo happens, values.categories array becomes empty
    loadProductInfo(slug)
  }, [slug])



  const loadCategories = async () => {
    const response = await getCategories()
    setValues({ ...values, categories: response.data })
  }

 
  // this function makes values.categories empty array
  const loadProductInfo = async (slug) => {
    const response = await getProductInfo(slug)
    console.log('Product info', response.data) 
  // response.data doesn't have fields named categories, but still it makes categories array 
   empty
    setValues({ ...values, ...response.data })
  }

  console.log('Categories see here', values.categories)
```

The response.data that is coming from loadProductInfo doesn't contain any field named categories. After loadCategories() finishes and sets the value from response, I see that categories array field gets filled, but after loadProductInfo() finishes, it again makes that categories array field empty, it's strange that the response.data coming from it doesn't have any fields named categories, so why is it making values.categories array field empty again? Is anything here related to state that I am not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the setters with the oldValues, maybe is there a conflict between your two api calls...

```
setValues(oldValues => ({ ...oldValues, ...response.data }))
```